# Getting a 504 error each time I try to post something to my website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, google-cloud-platform, pm2

I've been getting this error for awhile so I'm imagining I have something set up wrong and not a bug in the system. Everything worked on localhost, I'm just having a hard time getting it up and running on google cloud. You can see it here http://35.194.72.130/. On the left I am trying to post information to a database. In my util.js I have:

```
import "isomorphic-fetch"

export function addTime(name,time) {
    return fetch('http://35.194.72.130:3001/api/addtime', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, time }) 
    })
}
```

Then following instruction from a past professor, I added the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
            location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the proxy_pass to `http://35.194.72.130:3000` but then the site does not load. Its correctly receiving the information on the `times` pages via `"http://35.194.72.130:3001/api/list"`. Do you see what could be causing this 504 issue?

Edit: server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');

const app = express();
app.set("port", 3001);

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/json" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const config = {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "Austin",
    password: "astros5",
    database: "cubing"
};

const pool = new Pool(config);

app.post("/addtime", cors(), async (req,res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const time = req.body.time;
    // const timeStamp = dateFormat(time, dateFormat.masks.isoDateTime);
    
    const template = 'INSERT INTO times (name,time) VALUES ($1,$2)';
    const response = await pool.query(template, [name,time]);
    
    res.json({name: name, time: time});

});

app.get("/list", async (req,res) => {
    const template = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM times ORDER BY time ASC');
    res.json({times: template.rows});

})

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log('Server at: http://localhost:${app.get("port")}/');
});
```

Comment: There are three pieces to your puzzle. The client, the Nginx server (proxy), and the backend. HTTP 504 usually means that Nginx cannot connect to the backend. Your question does not show the code/configuration for the backend(s).

Comment: I added my backend. I don't really know what the issue is being as it worked on localhost.

Comment: Your backend has two pieces. The Node.js code and the database. Create an endpoint api in your code that just returns "Hello world' or similar so that you can verify that your Node.js is responding (by removing the database as a potential problem).

Comment: `app.get("/api/", (req,res) => {
 res.json({ message: "We did it!" });
});' I have this and if you go to <http://35.194.72.130/api/> it shows the message. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Now you know the path "client->nginx -> backend" works. That leaves the database part as your "most likey" problem. As some debugging/logging to see if you have a connection problem or a DB execution problem.

Comment: I'm imagining, because if you look at the list, the time I added on my locally shows up it must be a database execution problem. Is that right?